# Email Excel File as Attached for a Specified Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am facing an issue in this code while sending a specific google sheet (Email) as Excel attachment.

```
function sendReport() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").hideSheet();

  var message = {
    to: "email@domain.com",
    subject: "Weekly Reports",
    body: "Hi Team,\n\nPlease find attached summary reports, Thanks!\n\nThank you,\nMyNameHere",
    name: "MyNameHere",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMAIL").getAs(MimeType.xlsx).setName("Weekly Report")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMAIL").activate();
}
```

The Error I am facing is:

```
8:36:26 PM   Notice  Execution started
8:36:27 PM   Error   TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(...).getSheetByName(...).getAs is not a function
             sendReport   @ script.gs:10
```

after removing

```
.getSheetByName("EMAIL")
```

from row number 10 error goes as following:

```
8:38:43 PM   Notice   Execution started
8:38:43 PM   Error    Exception: Invalid argument
             sendReport   @ script.gs:10
```

Comment: I have little knowledge on App Scripting as i have just started working... So please ignore if I did a mistake and help please, thank you!

Comment: Also i would like to mention, code works fine if i change
.getAs(MimeType.xlsx) to .getAs(MimeType.PDF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you encountered such error is because there is no `getAs()` in [Sheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).

You can refer to this sample code on how to attached a specific sheet as an excel file in your email:

```
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()+"/export"+
            "?format=xlsx&"+
            "gid="+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMAIL").getSheetId();
                                                        
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName("Weekly Report.xlsx");

  var message = {
    to: "email@domain.com",
    subject: "Weekly Reports",
    body: "Hi Team,\n\nPlease find attached summary reports, Thanks!\n\nThank you,\nMyNameHere",
    name: "MyNameHere",
    attachments: [blob]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```

### What it does?

- Export a specific sheet using an [export url](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70) with `xlsx` as its format.
- Fetch the export url and get its blob using [getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getblob), use [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#setnamename) to rename the file. Include the file extension in the name.
- Attach the blob in your email.

### Output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue so I could update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @ron-m for the code, following error i am facing while running the code.

`11:16:47 PM    Error    Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: premium urlfetch.
sendExcel @ code.gs:6 `

Comment: How often do you call your function? Do you have other function which uses urlfetch method? Here is the [quota limits for google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: I just tried once and got this error, maybe its because of all other functions i am running from my id.
I made a new sheet from other GMAIL id and it worked, so it would be regarding my main GMAIL ID as it would have been exceeded quota?

Comment: Yes, you can check the daily quota limit for gmail account in the link that i've provided. But if you think that you are not exceeding the 20,000 limit per day for your gmail account, then your call interval might be the one which triggered the error. Since there are 86400 seconds a day, then (20,000/86400 = 0.23) it is safer to call urlfetch with 0.23 seconds interval. You can use [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) to introduce a delay

Comment: By the way, I updated the answer. You need to add the file extension `.xlsx` when you set the name of the blob.